# Displaying strings as card values

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

so I am building a deck of cards. for a blackjack game, and am having an issue showing the cards and then assigning it a value (The Facecards/Ace, is troubling) Can anyone give me a hand extracting the value but still showing the cards chosen as a string

```
suits = 'cdhs'
ranks = '23456789TJQK'
deck = tuple(''.join(card) for card in itertools.product(ranks,suits))
usrhand = random.sample(deck,2)
#print usrhand

fval = (str(usrhand[0]))[:1]
sval = (str(usrhand[1]))[:1]
#Need to check out TJQKA
#Error here, because val could be T
value = int(fval) + int(sval)

print("Your Hand: " + str(usrhand[0:1]))
print(value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rank_from_str = dict(zip("23456789TJQKA",[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11]))
print rank_from_str['A']

hand = "TTA"
hand_rank = sum(rank_from_str[card] for card in hand)
if hand_rank > 21: # if our hand is bigger than 21
   for i in range(hand.count("A")): #convert aces'
       hand_rank -= 10 #change 11 to 1 (subtract 10)
       if hand_rank <= 21: break #until we have less than 21
       #or until we run out of aces

print "HAND RANK:",hand_rank
```

Comment: Thanks Joran. I knew ONE of us would be able to muster basic reading comprehension. I still struggle with that! :)

Comment: Thanks! will i be able to just insert this after my usr hand? I am a little new to python. So this dict just correlates vals with numbers right?

Answer (score 0):

```
# assumes Python 3
import random

suits = {
    "C":0,
    "D":13,
    "H":26,
    "S":39
}
ranks = {
    "2":2,
    "3":3,
    "4":4,
    "5":5,
    "6":6,
    "7":7,
    "8":8,
    "9":9,
    "T":10,
    "J":11,
    "Q":12,
    "K":13,
    "A":14
}

deck = tuple(''.join(card) for card in itertools.product(ranks,suits))
hand = random.sample(deck, 2)

value = sum(ranks[card[0]] + suits[card[1]] for card in hand)

print("Your hand:", str(hand))
print("Value:", str(value))
```

Comment: Though neither of us really answered his question. He's implementing BLACKJACK. He needs to be able to get the card values for BLACKJACK. AsJd should be 21 :)

Comment: er... I don't cards :-P  but it shouldn't be hard to tweak the card values as needed.

Comment: The only issue is `A` is either 11 or 1. `A = 1 if value > 21 else 11`

Comment: @AdamSmith thats not quite true as it has to be 11 then subtracted once you total all the points... a conditional like you listed there wouldnt quite cut it and would lead to the player (or dealer) busting when they shouldnt consider `8,A,8` or `A67`, etc